# SPARQLWrapper not returning JSON

Tags: python, sparql, protege, sparqlwrapper

The following code should return a dictionary of the subject of all triples in the ontology. It, instead, returns the entire ontology as an XML string.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://purl.org/sudo/ontology/sudo.owl")
sparql.setQuery("""
    SELECT ?subject
    WHERE {?subject ?verb  ?object}
    """)

sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
print results.keys()
```

The above code works fine with a different ontology, which suggests that the ontology is the issue. I'm not sure what the issue with the ontology could be. I generated the ontology with Protege, it can load into vOWL, and it passes vOWL's ontology validation.

Comment: Can you share the ontology?

Comment: @Ignazio I thought it's the one in the example?

Comment: mac389, are you sure that `SOARQLWrapper` accepts remote RDF file path as an argument? AFAIK, this should be SPARQL endpoint address (which ends with `sparql` in most cases). If you want to query RDF file, perhaps you should load it into local store, possibly using [tag:rdflib].

Comment: Stanislav is right, even the first sentence makes this clear: *"This is a wrapper around a SPARQL service"* there is no built-in triple store, it's just a wrapper for the SPARQL HTTP protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SPARQLWrapper()`'s first argument [should be](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/doc/latest/SPARQLWrapper.Wrapper.SPARQLWrapper-class.html#__init__) a SPARQL endpoint address:

- [sparqlwrapper](/questions/tagged/sparqlwrapper) can't perform SPARQL queries against RDF files.
- if you want to query against an RDF file, you should load it into a local store using [rdflib](/questions/tagged/rdflib).

```python
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()
g.parse("http://purl.org/sudo/ontology/sudo.owl", format="xml")

qres = g.query("""
    SELECT DISTINCT ?s {
        ?s ?p ?o
    }""")

for row in qres:
    print("%s" % row)
```

If you *really* need SPARQL query results in JSON format ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/)):

```python
import sys
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib.plugins.sparql.results.jsonresults import JSONResultSerializer

g = Graph()
g.parse("http://purl.org/sudo/ontology/sudo.owl", format="xml")

qres = g.query("""
    SELECT DISTINCT ?s {
        ?s ?p ?o
    }""")

JSONResultSerializer(qres).serialize(sys.stdout)
```

If you wish to abstract from RDF serialization, you should use [owlready](/questions/tagged/owlready).

Comment: owlready would be a good option, but it requires Python 3. I'm stuck with 2.7 for this project.